# Can I merge an HTML element to an object?

Tags: javascript

I'd like to be able to take all the properties of an HTML element and attach them to an object so that the object will work just like the HTML element.

```
var clone = {};

function maker(obj){
  var e = document.createElement("div");
  e.innerHTML = "hello world";

  for(var key in e){
    obj[key] = e[key];
  }
}

maker(clone);
clone = <div>hello world</div>
```

This works to a small degree. `clone` will receive some of the properties of the element but I need to be able to do a deep iteration and i need deal with circular references to be able to get everything. I'm also wondering if there are other problems to what I'm trying to do?

Also, Yes I realize I can easily do:

```
function maker(){
  var e = document.createElement("div");
  e.innerHTML = "hello world";
  return e;
}

var clone = maker();
clone = <div>hello world</div
```

Another option that works ALMOST the way I want it:

```
var clone = {};

function maker(obj){
  var e = document.createElement("div");
  e.innerHTML = "hello world";
  obj.e = e.cloneNode(true);
}

maker(clone);
clone.e = <div>hello world</div>
```

But the optimal solution is to be able to write `maker(clone)` and have `clone = <div>hello world</div>`

Comment: You can use `cloneNode(true)` to clone an element and everything in it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode

Comment: `obj = e.cloneNode(true);` detaches obj's reference to clone. clone will equal `{}`

Comment: `console.log(obj.innerHTML)` will log `hello world`, so obj is not empty.

Comment: only if `console.log(obj.innerHTML)` is written within maker() function. outside of that function it equals `{}`

Comment: Maybe if you explain your purpose or exact need this would lead to better answers. From what most of us read it looks like `cloneNode` should do what you want. If you want to get something other then a direct clone of the HTML element then we need to better understand your intent.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`element.cloneNode(true)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode) to deep clone a HTML Element.

```
function maker(){
  var e = document.createElement("div");
  e.innerHTML = "hello world";
  return e.cloneNode(true);
}
```

Comment: that would require me to write `clone = maker();` which, as stated in my question, I knew would work already, I want to be able to pass clone into maker as an argument: `maker(clone)`

Comment: You didn't state that in the question

Comment: perhaps not directly. This only answers part of my question. I need the functionality of `.cloneNode()` but I also need `obj` to keep it's reference to `clone`

Answer (score 0):

Thats as close as I could get.

```js
function maker(target, context) {
  context = context || this;

  var source = document.createElement("p");
  source.innerHTML = "hello world";
  context[target] = source.cloneNode(true);
}

// Global Scope
var clone = {};
maker('clone');
console.log(clone);

// Object scope - maker in obj
var obj = {
  'objClone': {},
  'method': function() {
    maker('objClone', this);
  }
}
obj.method();
console.log(obj.objClone);

// Object Scope - maker outside obj2
var obj2 = {
  'objClone': {}
}
maker('objClone', obj2); // you will need context here
console.log(obj2.objClone);
```

Comment: The downvote is because your original answer just told me how to retrieve the element from the DOM and set it to the `obj` variable. Which has nothing to do with my question. Also the extra code you added looks like it has a bunch of weirdness. `clone` is defined in a function and then used globally out of scope. also `maker()` sets clone, then immediately returns `clone` which also sets `clone`... nutty.

Comment: Your question is to get an object from html? So you dont want to get it from the dom? Which means you have to create the element in js, right? - The "weirdness" is testing the properties of the function by the way :D

Comment: Yes I create the element in JS, I do that on the 4th line of my example. My question is to clone that element onto another object without loosing that objects reference to the outer scope

Comment: That actually looks pretty darn close to the functionality I want. my only problem now is that I can't guarantee that `clone` will always be in the global scope. I don't think javascript has any way to reference the scope from where-ever `maker()` was called from is there? ex: instead of your line `window[target] = . . .` we could write `invokedScope[target] = . . .` Then I think it would work perfect!

Comment: check it out :)